# Hashlips Engine gives error after generating 1 image and NO Metadata is generated

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, nvm

I am not able to generate any metadata in Hashlips engine and it stops after building 1 image. Looked around a lot of solutions but nothing seems to rectify.

I am getting this error :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:
> The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer,
> TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

The error is shown on these lines:

```
const writeMetaData = (_data) => {
fs.writeFileSync(${buildDir}/json/_metadata.json, _data);
};

fs.writeFileSync(
${buildDir}/json/${_editionCount}.json,
JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2)
);

saveMetaDataSingleFile(abstractedIndexes[0]);
```

**Node:v14.21.3
NPM:6.14.18**

Any help is appreciated!!
Many thanks